# jQuery's .split() not converting a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, split, tostring

I have made an AJAX search field. Ajax search works and items are being successfully added. When I remove the added search items. I am getting the clicked on added search values. Converting them to an array and then I will do inArray and remove the matched ones. But the problem is when I use **split** for jQuery. It isn't converting a simple string to an array. Here is the HTML.

```js
$('.placeholder').on("click", "li", function() {

  parent = jQuery('.supplier-ajax'); // Parent
  id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  slug = jQuery(this).attr('slug');
  supplierval = parent.find('#product_supplier').val();

  console.log(parent);
  console.log('placeholderclick');
  console.log(slug);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(supplierval);
  console.log(typeof supplierval)


  supplierarray = $(supplierval).toString().split(",");
  console.log(supplierarray);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="search-field supplier-ajax">
     <div class="placeholder">
      <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-supplier-field" class="supplier-field field form-control valid" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
      <ul class="placeholder-items">
                <li class="supplier-ajax-placeholder" id="726" slug="bottle">Bottle</li>
            </ul>
     </div>
     <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <div class="hidden" id="suggesstion-box">
      <ul>
                <li id="726" slug="bottle">Bottle</li>
                <li id="1011" slug="eurobottle">Eurobottle</li>
                <li id="612" slug="bottle-promotions">Bottle Promotions</li>
            </ul>
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw hidden"></i>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" id="supplier-nonce" name="" value="93b8e7346b">
     <input type="hidden" id="product_supplier" name="supplier" value="bottle">
    </span>
```

The console outputs

```
placeholderclick
bottle
726
bottle
string
["[object Object]"]0: "[object Object]"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

The typeof the supplierval is string but still **split** does not work. I have tried removing .toString() from supplierarray but then it gives a .split(); function not found error. I dont know what is the problem.

Why isn't split working on a simple string who's typeof is also string.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/t3xn1v7m/

Comment: Juts `supplierarray = supplierval.split(",");`

Comment: Yes, as Satpal said, the reason being you're storing the text as a string variable then converting that variable into a JQuery object that .toString() doesn't know what to do with.

Comment: `Why isn't split working on a simple string who's typeof is also string.` - You are not doing `split` on a simple string. You are wrapping `supplierval`, the simple string, into a jQuery object, no no longer a simple string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating jQuery object using `$()` and then converting that object to string using `.toString()`.

*Just use* `.split()` on `supplierval` variable

```
supplierarray = supplierval.split(",");
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks alot. Im weak at jquery. Didn't know $ converts a string into an object..